# Why doesn't this code work if it has a space in it?

Tags: bash

Apologies for being dumb. I tried to find an answer, but to no avail. If it has been answered before, (which is likely) then I haven't seen it.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p “Whatisyourname” name
echo "Hello $name"
^This piece of code does work.

#!/bin/bash
read -p “What is your name” name
echo "Hello $name"
```

^This piece of code does not work. It prints the first word as a prompt (`What`). After entering input (x), it will say

```
Command 'x' not found, but can be installed with: sudo snap install x
```

Just wondering why it comes out like this.

I know I could just separate it all out with echo, read, and then echo. That works even with spaces, thankfully. I'm just curious why this doesn't.

Comment: First problem is that you've used smart quotes, “...”, and you should be using straight quotes "..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your quote marks are not ASCII quotes (`“` and `"` are different if you look closer), therefore they don't prevent word splitting by the shell.

```
read -p “Whatisyourname” name
```

The prompt message is `“Whatisyourname”`.

```
read -p “What is your name” name
```

The prompt message is `“What`. The rest (`is`, `your`, `name”` and `name`) would be assigned to variables according to the user input.

You mean

```
read -p "What is your name" name
```

Comment: All hail our senior programmers, who are wiser and more powerful than us.

Comment: And stop writing code with a word processor. What editor are you using to write your code?